# Filtering dropdown list in MS access hides existing values in older records

Tags: microsoft-access

I have Microsoft Access database. In this database I have multiple tables. In one table I store details about contracts we have with our business partners. in second table I have details about orders.

I'm entering orders into database with a form. On this form I have a dropdown list that contains contracts numbers from the first table.

Since we have renewed some contract with our business partners and thus the valid contracts now have different contract number I went and filtered the mentioned dropdown list to only show numbers of valid contracts.

The problem is I'm facing nos is that if I navigate to a old record that contains a contract number from an old contract that is no longer valid the dropdown list is shown empty.

So how can I filter dropdown list so that it will show only valid contract numbers in its selection but still show already stored contract number even if it is form currently invalid contract?

---

EDIT: Is the cause of my problem perhaps the fact that in my contracts table the contract number is not the main index field but instead I left Access to create a ID field that is populated automatically with record ID's?

| ID | ContactNo. |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 107029 |
| 2 | 106905 |
| 3 | 123325 |
| 4 | 123169 |
| 5 | 146548 |
| 6 | 146305 |